# Getting line number of word document text using lxml with python

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I was using xml.etree.ElementTree previously, and was asked to add line numbers to the information I'm parsing from a word document.

But, I'm having trouble getting it to work properly. Does anybody have experience using lxml with the attribute sourceline to get line numbers of a text document?

I have something like this

## Returns tree object to be parsed for text

```
from lxml.etree import XML

CONTENT_NAMESPACE = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types}"
WORD_NAMESPACE = '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}' 
PARAGRAPH = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'p' 
TEXT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 't' 
STYLE = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'pStyle'
TABLE = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'tbl'
ROW   = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'tr'
CELL  = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'tc'
CONTENT = WORD_NAMESPACE + 'r'


def populate_tree(path):
    try:
        docx = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
        xml_content = docx.read('word/document.xml')
        docx.close()
        tree = XML(xml_content)
    except Exception as e:
        raise(e)
```

## Finds all tables in document

**This function takes each row of the table and creates a list of string objects, and adds them to a master list, separating each table into it's own list of strings.**

```
def parse_table(tree):
    strObj = ''
    list = []
    masterList
    for table in tree.iter(TABLE):
        for row in table.iter(ROW):
            for cell in row.iter(CELL):
                for node in cell.iter(PARAGRAPH):
                    for rel in node.iter(CONTENT):
                        for T in rel.iter(TEXT):
                            length = len(T.text)
                            if (T.text[length-1] == ',' or T.text[length-1] == '.'):
                                strObj+= T.text + '\n'
                            else:
                                strObj += T.text + ' '
                list.append(strObj)
                strObj = ''
        masterList.append(list)
        list = []
    return masterList
```

there a way to incorporate sourceline into what I have to get the line number from the document? I don't mind if I need to parse the whole text to get this ability. So if I need to alter what I've done and parse the entire text, maybe that's the way I need to go? I haven't really understood fully how sourceline works to incorporate it properly.

## Edit

I added a test document [here](https://spaces.hightail.com/space/JZDD5eornR)

Hopefully, the idea is to match the line numbers I have when I parse the document to the same line numbers that word produces when you turn on line numbers.

As an example, I would start from page 1, and number the lines continuously from line 1 on the first page all the way to the end of the document. The document I uploaded ends at line 75.

What I'm trying to do is parse the document that somebody else wrote, and flag requirements (REQ-1234), signals, and other areas where the document might need to be updated. I would like to provide line numbers for the person to check when I flag issues with the document.

## Edit 2

I found this code in another stackoverflow question, but there aren't really any examples of how to use it. Can anybody provide an example of how this might be used?

```
# Force python XML parser not faster C accelerators
# because we can't hook the C implementation
import sys
sys.modules['_elementtree'] = None
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import zipfile

class LineNumberingParser(ET.XMLParser):
    def _start_list(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Here we assume the default XML parser which is expat
        # and copy its element position attributes into output Elements
        element = super(self.__class__, self)._start_list(*args, **kwargs)
        element._start_line_number = self.parser.CurrentLineNumber
        element._start_column_number = self.parser.CurrentColumnNumber
        element._start_byte_index = self.parser.CurrentByteIndex
        return element

    def _end(self, *args, **kwargs):
        element = super(self.__class__, self)._end(*args, **kwargs)
        element._end_line_number = self.parser.CurrentLineNumber
        element._end_column_number = self.parser.CurrentColumnNumber
        element._end_byte_index = self.parser.CurrentByteIndex
        return element

    def get_tree(self,path):
        docx = zipfile.ZipFile(path)
        xml_content = docx.read('word/document.xml') 
        docx.close()
        self.text_tree =xml_content
```

The above code seems like it might be useful in getting line numbers into the XML that's parsed by xml.etree.ElementTree

Comment: Can you provide an example document + the result you need?

Comment: I'm trying to put something together now, barebones of what I am working with.

Comment: I put a document up, and a link to it, and an edit describing what I'm trying to do.